# QCoreApplication::notifyInternal Segmentation fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, notify

Hello I'm developing a shared library  in c++ and I'm testing it using a QT interface. Everything seemed ok, but suddenly the application crashed and give me the following core dump:

> Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault. 0  0x00401b26
>   in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from
>   /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> (gdb) bt
>
> 0  0x00401b26 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)
>   () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 1  0x0043093a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 2  0x009d7855 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
>
> 3  0x009db668 in ?? () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
>
> 4  0x009db848 in g_main_context_iteration () from
>   /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
>
> 5  0x00430565 in
>   QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags)
>   () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 6  0x05cedbe5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
>
> 7  0x00400609 in
>   QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags) ()
>   from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 8  0x00400a8a in
>   QEventLoop::exec(QFlags) () from
>   /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 9  0x0040500f in QCoreApplication::exec() () from
>   /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
>
> 10 0x05c2ae07 in QApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
>
> 11 0x0804cd72 in main ()

I'm running in ubuntu 10.10 installed in a SD card, and I'm using QT 4.7.0. In Windows the application works ok, and in Linux too, until the application crashed at a random time. I don't know if a QT bug with ubuntu or something like that, because I have read in internet, applications with similar core dump.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably because an event was posted to an object that was deleted before returning to the event loop. Do you use `delete object` or use `object->deleteLater()`?

Comment: Hello andref, I'm only deleting the objects into destructor of the class. I think that, maybe, the stack of one of my threads grows up to much and this cause the crashed, but I don't know.

Comment: Well, you can check the other stacks in GDB, I suppose. There is no particular trigger for this crash?

Comment: The stacks seems ok and no, the crash is random

Comment: Couple more things to check: do QObjects live in more than one thread? Is the crash happening just on Ubuntu or on any Linux distro?

Comment: The error was in the UDP´s Sockets. In Ubunut, and CENTOS5, the QT's sockets didn't work correctly and I don't knwo why. I changed the QT's sockets, and I used UDP sockets developed in C++ and now the aplication works fine.